# Wordpress how to filter posts basing on custom field in certain post type

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type, custom-wordpress-pages

I have the following code:

```
function filter_by_user( $query ) {
      
$user = get_current_user_id();

if ( ! $meta_query ) {
    $meta_query = [];
}

// Append our meta query
$meta_query[] = [
    'key'     => 'id_customerJK',
        'value'   => $user,
        'compare' => 'LIKE',
];

$query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
}
    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'filter_by_user', 9998 );
```

And it works very well, however it executes itself on every page. I would like it to only execute in the custom post type "customer_bill" singular.

Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the following conditions to alter the query:

- [`is_single`<sup>Docs</sup>](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_single/) function to check whether the query is for an existing single post.

AND

- Using `get('post_type')` method on the "$query" variable.

```php
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'filter_by_user', 9998);

function filter_by_user($query)
{
    if (
        is_single()
        &&
        'customer_bill' == $query->get('post_type')
       ) 
    {

        $user = get_current_user_id();

        $meta_query = $meta_query ?: [];

        $meta_query[] = [
            'key'     => 'id_customerJK',
            'value'   => $user,
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ];

        $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
if ( is_singular('customer_bill') ) {
// Your Code
```

or

```
if ( ! is_singular('customer_bill') ) {
    return;
}
// Your Code
```